# F# Mutable list is returning an error stating it is not mutable

Tags: debugging, f#, queue, mutable

I'm trying to implement a queue in F#. One way I thought about going about it is using a mutable list. I believe the logic is all right, however when I run the code I get the error

```
/home/runner/main.fs(12,5): error FS0027: This value is not mutable. Consider using the mutable keyword, e.g. 'let mutable queue = expression'.
compiler exit status 1
^[[3;1R
```

This is my implementation code

```
let create_job_list jobCount resultLis =
    let resultLis =
        [for i in 1..jobCount do yield System.Random().Next(10)]
    resultLis

let job_list = create_job_list 10 []

let mutable queue = []

let push x queue =
    printfn "%A" x
    queue <- (x::queue)

let pop resQueue =
    let resQ = resQueue |> List.rev
    match resQ with
    | head::tail -> printfn "%A" head; queue <- (tail |> List.rev)
    | [] -> failwith "No more jobs to do right now." 

let rec jobQueue job_list =
    match job_list with
    | head::tail when head%2=1 -> (push head queue) |> ignore; jobQueue tail
    | head::tail when head%2=0 -> (pop queue) |> ignore; jobQueue tail
    | _ -> failwith "Empty list"
```

The error tells me to use `let mutable queue = expression` but I'm using `let mutable queue = []`

Where am I going wrong? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have declared queue as mutable, but you are passing it as an argument that isn't mutable anymore. Since your `queue` variable is visible inside the push and pop you don't need to have it as parameters.

This should compile:

```
  let create_job_list jobCount resultLis =
    let resultLis =
        [for i in 1..jobCount do yield System.Random().Next(10)]
    resultLis

  let job_list = create_job_list 10 []

  let mutable queue = []

  let push x=
      printfn "%A" x
      queue <- (x::queue)

  let pop resQueue =
      let resQ = resQueue |> List.rev
      match resQ with
      | head::tail -> printfn "%A" head; queue <- (tail |> List.rev)
      | [] -> failwith "No more jobs to do right now." 

  let rec jobQueue job_list =
      match job_list with
      | head::tail when head%2=1 -> (push head) |> ignore; jobQueue tail
      | head::tail when head%2=0 -> (pop) |> ignore; jobQueue tail
      | _ -> failwith "Empty list"
```

Answer (score 2):

What you need is to pass `queue` [by reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/parameters-and-arguments#passing-by-reference). Your `push` function should then look something like this:

```
let push x (queue: byref<_>) =
    printfn "%A" x
    queue <- (x::queue)
```

and the `jobQueue` like this

```
let rec jobQueue job_list =
    match job_list with
    | head::tail when head%2=1 -> (push head &queue) |> ignore; jobQueue tail
    | head::tail when head%2=0 -> (pop queue) |> ignore; jobQueue tail
    | _ -> failwith "Empty list"
```

I haven't tried this code, but it should at least get you started.

By the way, I guess you are aware that .Net already has a Queue implementation?